# maven project directory structure in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Maven and created/converted a web-app using Maven to Eclipse IDE format.
I am kind of confused with the directory structure created in eclipse by maven.There are apparently 2 src folders, Java Resources - src/main/java and src/main/java in eclipse.But if you look at the workspace under c drive, there is only src/main/java., java resources folderis not visible though that's where the actual java files reside.(am i right?)Everytime i create a new package under java resources-src/main/java, it gets created under the other src/main/java folder as well, seems like both are inter-connected, but I can't create the package directly under src/main/java though even if i want to.Also there is no web-content folder when created through maven.  I can put my css, js files under src/main/webapp/resources folder. Where do I put the hibernate/spring config.xml files? src/main/resources folder or src/main/webapp/resources folder? also what about the spring-mvc-servlet.xmil file?currently i have it under web-inf folder. Why does the various resources files live under multiple folders and not a single location?

Also, I created a junit test and placed my spring/hibernate config.xml file under src/main/resources folder and junit test worked fine. I know it has to be under test/main/resources folder but i dont have a test folder and so had to go with the other resource folder. But when I tried to run the application, I get bean name not found error though the config.xml file is located under src/main/resources folder. I put it under webapp folder, still it throws the same error since I have an Autowire annotation in one of my service layer. Seems like its not reading my spring.config xml.

So whats the ideal place to put config(spring/hibernate) files/css files/ javascript files etc.?

Comment: Sounds like your eclipse is not correctly understanding the maven project layout - have you got [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin installed in eclipse?  And what is `test/main/resources` - are you sure you are follwing the [standard dir layout for maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)?  Finally, given you are using eclipse + maven + spring, you might be best off installing [STS](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all) - it eclipse already configured with common plugins for spring and maven development.

Comment: @sbk: sorry I mean src/test/java, there is no resources folder i believe. yes, i am using std lib layout, created the structure using mvn web-app arechetype..thanks for the pointer, i will install that plugin. also regarding my issue, my problem was that i named my package differently through maven when creating the dir structure, and modified it manually through eclipse. so everytime i run the -Dwtp command, it overwrites my changes, i forgot to change the package name under pom.xml. Now I renamed it everywhere and its working... thanks...